# Disable horizontal autoscroll in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, autoscroll

I have a JTable that is filled dynamically.
It has only two columns, the first is a boolean value and the second is a string.

The problem is that when I select a row in the string column, the table autoscrolls to the right hiding the first column.

How do I change this behaviour?

If I disable autoscroll, the user is not able to scroll to the bottom through the arrow keys.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call:

`jscrollpane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);`

which will make sure no horizontal `JScrollBar` is created for the `JScrollPane`.

Perhaps also need to ensure the `JScrollPane` fits the `JTable` horizontally via:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane jscrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Comment: @koplersky glad to be of help :)